# I want to add a console.log statement that logs the value of an undeclared variable. How do I do it?

Tags: javascript, variables, console.log

I'm learning Javascript from scratch and I've gone over the basic stuff to get a grasp of terms and such. The instructions are as follows:

1. First, declare your variable numberX. Do not initialize it (which means, don't give it a starting value) yet
2. Add a console.log statement that explains in words what you think the value of x is
3. Add a console.log statement that logs the value of numberX.
4. Now initialize your variable numberX with a number (also called an integer in computer science terms)
5. Next, add a console.log statement that explains what you think the value of numberX is
6. Add a console.log statement that logs the value of numberX

... and I think I'm following the steps but I'm not sure. (this is my code ->):

```js
// step 1
let numberX;

// step 2
console.log('I think the value of numberX is 19');

// step 3
console.log((numberX = 19));

// step 4
numberX = 2;

// step 5
console.log((numberX = 20));

// step 6
console.log(numberX);
```

Comment: Step 3 needs to be `console.log'(numberX);` and step 5 needs to look like Step 2, outputting text.

Comment: Step 3 doesn't say to give numberX a value

Comment: I think you may need to take a step back and re-evaluate what exactly is being asked of you in each of these steps; in the example you provided, you have answered extremely similar questions in completely different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I've reevaluated, maybe I'm closer to what's really being asked.

```
let numberX;
console.log('I think the value of numberX is the number 19');
console.log(numberX);
numberX = 2;
console.log('I think the value of numberX is an integer');
console.log(numberX);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what the exercise is asking:

```
let numberX;

console.log('I think the value of numberX is 19');

console.log(numberX);

numberX = 2;

console.log('I think the value of numberX is 2');

console.log(numberX);
```